# Analog `fs.readdirSync` node.js without recursive

Tags: node.js, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I try get only html files to my folder. But my code get all folders into my root folders and return result me. I want to get only `.html` files.

My structure project

`src
    folder
    folder2
    index.html
    inner.html`

I need to only `index.html` and `inner.html`
My code:

```
function generateHtmlPlugins(templateDir) {
  const templateFiles = fs.readdirSync(join(rootDir, templateDir));

  return templateFiles.map(item => {
    const parts = item.split('.');
    const name = parts[0];
    const extension = parts[1];

    return new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: `${name}.html`,
      template: join(rootDir, `./${templateDir}/${name}.${extension}`),
      inject: false
    });
  });
}

const htmlPlugins = generateHtmlPlugins('./src');
```

Please, help me send only `.html` files into my function

Comment: You just need to add a condition, like `if(extension === 'html')`...you should also use `filter` instead of `map`

Comment: @Hackerman I try use `if (extension === html)`, but i get error `TypeError: arguments[i].apply is not a function`

Comment: @Hackerman thanks for filter. This work

Comment: Glad to help @Aleksandr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need filter your files before `map`

```
function generateHtmlPlugins(templateDir) {
  const templateFiles = fs.readdirSync(join(rootDir, templateDir));
  const htmlFiles = templateFiles.filter(item => item.split('.')[1] === 'html');

  return htmlFiles.map(item => {
    const parts = item.split('.');
    const name = parts[0];
    const extension = parts[1];

    return new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: `${name}.html`,
      template: join(rootDir, `./${templateDir}/${name}.${extension}`),
      inject: false
    });
  });
}

const htmlPlugins = generateHtmlPlugins('./src');
```